# if triangle QRS has incenter, what is the incenter of triangle xyz

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

if triangle ABC has incenter I how is it possible to show the circumcenter of triangle BIC lies on the circumcircle of triangle ABC?

[![ddiagram][1]][1]

D is the circumcenter of BIC

Comment: Angle chase.  Extend AI to meet the circumcircle at D, the midpoint of arc BC, as in your diagram.  Chase the angle DBC and hence DBI and BID,  Similarly switch B and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join $AI$ and extend till it intersects circumcircle.
If possible Ray$AI$ does not intersect $D$ but at $D'$ .
Join $D'B$ and $D'C$ .
By angle chasing, 
$\angle BID' = \angle IBD'$ 
And
$\angle CID' = \angle ICD'$.
Therefore, $BD'$ = $ID'$ = $CD'$.
$\implies$ $D'$ is circumcentre of $\triangle BIC$ .
As given $D$ is circumcentre of $\triangle BIC$ .
Contradiction to considerations,
$D$ coincides $D'$.
Hence, proved.

Comment: Hi, how would I go about angle chasing to prove ∠BID′=∠IBD′  And ∠CID′=∠ICD'

Comment: Let $\angle AIB=x$and $\angle ABI=y$. $\angle BID'=x+y$ . $\angle CBI=y$ and $\angle IBD'=x $ as $\square ABCD'$ is cyclic. Thus $\angle BID'=\angle IBD'= x+y$. Repeat the process and get $\angle CID'=\angle ICD'$.

Answer (score 0):

In the standard notation $$\measuredangle BIC=180^{\circ}-\frac{\beta}{2}-\frac{\gamma}{2}=180^{\circ}-\frac{180^{\circ}-\alpha}{2}=90^{\circ}+\frac{\alpha}{2},$$ which says that in the circumcircle of $\Delta BIC$ the arc $BC$ is equal to $180^{\circ}+\alpha$.

Thus the arc $BIC$ is $$360^{\circ}-\left(180^{\circ}+\alpha\right)=180^{\circ}-\alpha$$
and since $$\measuredangle BDC+\measuredangle BAC=180^{\circ},$$we obtain  that the circumcenter of $\Delta BIC$ is placed on the circumcircle of $\Delta ABC.$

Comment: hi, quick question, what do β,γ, and α represent?

Comment: @user604720 They are angles of the triangle. $\measuredangle BAC=\alpha$, $\measuredangle ABC=\beta$ and $\measuredangle ACB=\gamma.$